# How to change the border color of ngTagsInput with/without focus?

Tags: ng-tags-input

Given this HTML that declares the tags-input directive:

```
<tags-input class="bootstrap" ng-model="selected">
    <auto-complete source="getList($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

This CSS doesn't change the border to blue:

```
.bootstrap .tags {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

This CSS doesn't change the border to red when ngTagsInput gets the focus

```
.bootstrap .tags:focused {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the HTML when `tags-input` is in focus, it applies a `focused` class when the input is focused. We can utilize that class to override our CSS.

I put the following CSS and it works for me:

```
.bootstrap .tags{
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.bootstrap .tags.focused {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

And, what you tried to do in question (`:focused`) is not a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), `:focus` is! :)

Here's the sample [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4c0WpbYVgvbz3CZn5BWU?p=preview)